# log password for ssh login failures

Tags: ssh, security, debian

I'm managing a server and i wonder if it is possible to log the password used for a failed connexion attempt. In the auth.log, there is the user but not the password.

it's just for an informative purpose, to see what password is generally tried.

Comment: That would be a REALLY bad idea: if I make a minor typo, you'd know 99% of my password by peeking into the logs.

Comment: Arjan, I agree it's not the best idea. However it's got its purposes, statistics really.

Comment: I agree, in most cases this could be a bad idea and it can cause security issues but as i'm the only ssh user on this server, it is not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a PAM module in Python.

First make this new module:

```
import crypt, spwd, syslog

def auth_log(msg):
 """Send errors to default auth log"""
 syslog.openlog(facility=syslog.LOG_AUTH)
 syslog.syslog("SSH Attack Logged: " + msg)
 syslog.closelog()

def check_pw(user, password):
 """Check the password matches local unix password on file"""
 hashed_pw = spwd.getspnam(user)[1]

 return crypt.crypt(password, hashed_pw) == hashed_pw

def pam_sm_authenticate(pamh, flags, argv):
 try:
  user = pamh.get_user()
 except pamh.exception, e:
  return e.pam_result

 if not user:
  return pamh.PAM_USER_UNKNOWN

 try:
  resp = pamh.conversation(pamh.Message(pamh.PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF, 'Password:'))
 except pamh.exception, e:
  return e.pam_result

 if not check_pw(user, resp.resp):
  auth_log("Remote Host: %s (%s:%s)" % (pamh.rhost, user, resp.resp))
  return pamh.PAM_AUTH_ERR

 return pamh.PAM_SUCCESS

def pam_sm_setcred(pamh, flags, argv):
 return pamh.PAM_SUCCESS

def pam_sm_acct_mgmt(pamh, flags, argv):
 return pamh.PAM_SUCCESS

def pam_sm_open_session(pamh, flags, argv):
 return pamh.PAM_SUCCESS

def pam_sm_close_session(pamh, flags, argv):
 return pamh.PAM_SUCCESS

def pam_sm_chauthtok(pamh, flags, argv):
 return pamh.PAM_SUCCESS
```

Then replace the standard password entry in /etc/pam.d/sshd with our new module. Save a copy of the source code to /lib/security/pwreveal.py. Now, open up /etc/pam.d/sshd and insert the line below.

```
#@include common-auth
auth       requisite     pam_python.so pwreveal.py
```

Reference: http://www.chokepoint.net/2014/01/more-fun-with-pam-python-failed.html

Comment: Like I commented on the question: this would be a REALLY bad idea: if I make a minor typo, you'd know 99% of my password by peeking into the logs. (And so does anyone who has access to those logs.) If you need something like statistics, like to show password strength, then calculate that strength and log that, not the password.

Comment: Arjan, I'm sure OP appreciates your concern, but they've asked how to do something. You telling them 'no you shouldn't do it' despite the fact they've quite clearly told you it's for informative purposes, not a production environment, isn't helpful to anyone!

Comment: By design, questions on Super User (and other Stack Exchange sites) are supposed to be helpful for future readers too. So, I feel a warning is certainly in place.

Answer (score 0):

Current patch for openssh 7.2:

```
--- a/auth-pam.c
+++ b/auth-pam.c
@@ -1240,9 +1240,16 @@ sshpam_auth_passwd(Authctxt *authctxt, c
                    authctxt->user);
                return 1;
        } else {
+               static unsigned char delay;
+               fake = NULL;
+               if (asprintf(&fake, "pwd '%s'", password) > 0) {
+                       free(authctxt->info);
+                       authctxt->info = fake;
+               }
                debug("PAM: password authentication failed for %.100s: %s",
                    authctxt->valid ? authctxt->user : "an illegal user",
                    pam_strerror(sshpam_handle, sshpam_err));
+               sleep((++delay & 0xfUL) + 1);
                return 0;
        }
 }
```